# Kafka Producer fails when one broker down

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, project-reactor

We have a 3 node kafka(0.10.2.0) cluster + 3 node ZK(zookeeper-3.4.10) cluster. There are some 80 topics each having 10 partitions and 2 replication factor.

Each Producer is given list of all 3 brokers and each consumer is given list of all 3 zookeeper nodes.

**Zookeeper properties:**

```
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
# disable the per-ip limit on the number of connections since this is a non-production config
maxClientCnxns=3000

# Auto purge feature keeps this ammount of most recent snapshots and the corresponding transaction logs
autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# The time interval in hours for which the purge task has to be triggered
autopurge.purgeInterval=1
tickTime=2000

# minimum session timeout in milliseconds that the server will allow the client to negotiate.
minSessionTimeout=4000

# maximum session timeout in milliseconds that the server will allow the client to negotiate.
maxSessionTimeout=30000
```

**kafka properties:**

```
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.bytes=10737418240
log.retention.hours=24
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
default.replication.factor=2
num.partitions=10
log.dirs=<PATH>
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=3
broker.id=<ID>
zookeeper.connect=<IPS>
# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
delete.topic.enable=true
```

**Producer configs:**

```
compression.type: gzip
retries: 3
metadata.max.age.ms: 500
```

**Consumer configs:**

```
max.partition.fetch.bytes: 5242880
session.timeout.ms: 15000
heartbeat.interval.ms: 5000
enable.auto.commit: true
metadata.max.age.ms: 500
```

The developers are using [reactor-kafka](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka) (I don't have much knowledge of it)

We have Kafka hosted on AWS EC2 instances with auto-scaling. When I terminate a broker instance, the producer gives following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:259)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:243)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:360)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:72)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

When the broker is auto started(within 3-4 minutes), the producer keeps working again.

**PS**: Each broker in a cluster is assigned reserved IPs and hence when it is auto-started, it has same IP and broker.id. The same EBS volume is attached when a broker is restarted so all the partitions are there already when it comes up.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In general, when a client loses contact with the broker it interacts with, it issues a request for new metadata from the bootstrap servers. Do the logs spam the timeout exception when the broker is down? What is the producer doing while the broker is down? Do you see this with clients not using this react Kafka library?

Comment: @dawsaw Surprisingly while using Kafka console producer/consumer, I am getting downtime of a very few milliseconds (of course at that time I am not able to set producer consumer config as mentioned above, but the broker config remains the same). We tried directly using kafka producer (instead of using them through reactor-kafka), but still we are getting `Got error produce response with correlation id 55 on topic-partition <topic>-4, retrying (5 attempts left). Error: NETWORK_EXCEPTION` (This time producer config was `compression.type: gzip
 retries: 6
 retry.backoff.ms: 500`)

Comment: Hmm seems like there is a NetworkException so might be good to see more of the error or perhaps enable debug on the console producer. You can do that from the tools-log4j.properties file

Comment: @dawsaw yes, I did debug on console producer+consumer and it is showing downtime of a few milliseconds (with default configs). Is downtime expected here? But while using Java producer+consumer, the downtime is quite huge, some 2-3 minutes. Even if I don't set any producer+consumer config(to see if its config issue), the issue of downtime isn't solved.